# How to run ajc from Java?

Tags: java, aop, aspectj

I'm trying to run `ajc` compiler from Java (not from Maven or Ant!). The question is which Maven dependency do I need and which class is an entry point? The best option I have now is `org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main` from `org.aspectj:aspectjtools:1.7.2`. Am I right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. In your Java project you need `aspectjrt.jar` (for the runtime) and `aspectjtools.jar` (for the compiler) on the class path. Then you can build an AspectJ project and create a JAR file containing aspects and classes like this:

```java
import org.aspectj.tools.ajc.Main;

public class AjcRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String[] ajcArgs = {
            "-sourceroots", "c:\\my\\aspectj_project\\src",
            "-outjar", "my_aspects.jar"
        };
        Main.main(ajcArgs);
    }
}
```

Afterwards you can test the result on the console like this, assuming you have a class `Application` with a `main` method:

```
java -cp C:\path\to\aspectjrt.jar;my_aspects.jar Application
```